# Is it possible to use AWS Lightsail with external DNS service?

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I want to host an application as Lightsail container service using a (sub)domain managed by a not AWS related DNS service. Is it possible to use a custom domain in that case? I can only find information about using the Lightsail or Route 53 DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Given the limited information in the question, my answer is going to be more of a general guidance.

---

Indeed, from the documentation, it appears as if your DNS must be managed by either Lightsail or Route53.

However, you mentioned you could use a subdomain for your application. If you own `example.com` and want to make your application available on e.g. `web.app.example.com` and potentially `api.app.example.com`, you'd be using `app.example.com` as your root domain. You can employ the technique of DNS delegation with Route53 [[See docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html)]. This way, only the subdomain `app.example.com` would be managed by Route53, whereas your root domain would still be managed by whatever provider you're using.

Comment: That looks like a valid solution. Will give it a try!